# What is difference between scaling and sampling of bitmap?

Tags: android, bitmap, android-bitmap

I have confusion between android bitmap scaling and sampling here may have two code one for scaling and another for sampling can anyone help me for identifying working of this two code and what is main differences between them.

**Scaling :**

```
public static Bitmap getScaleBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, int newWidth, int newHeight) {
    int width = bitmap.getWidth();
    int height = bitmap.getHeight();
    float scaleWidth = ((float) newWidth) / width;
    float scaleHeight = ((float) newHeight) / height;

    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);
    return Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, false);
}
```

**Sampling :**

```
mImageView.setImageBitmap(decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(getResources(),R.id.myimage, 100, 100));

public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(Resources res, int resId,
        int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);

    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);
}

public static int calculateInSampleSize(
            BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

        final int halfHeight = height / 2;
        final int halfWidth = width / 2;

        while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) >= reqHeight
                && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) >= reqWidth) {
            inSampleSize *= 2;
        }
    }

    return inSampleSize;
}
```

here both code perform image resizing but different way so how I can identify which one is good and simple.

Answer (score 1):

First code, takes bitmap and creates new smaller bitmap - you would use memmory for the bigger bitmap.

Second code takes resource. `inJustDecodeBounds` Makes it so you not load the whole bitmap into memmory just information for it. Then calculate how it should be sized,  and then again when set `inJustDecodeBounds` to false load into memmory reduced version of the image.  So you would use memmory only for the decoded image

[Oficial docs](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/load-bitmap.html)

Answer (score 0):

**Scaling**: First, you decode the whole bitmap in memory, then you scale it.

**Sampling**: You get the required scaled bitmap without loading the whole bitmap in memory.